# Use Jimp in a React application

Tags: reactjs, jimp

I have a basic React app. I'm trying to use `jimp` library to manipulate images.
However I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value [object Object] is not a constructor or null`.
I read that `jimp` can only be used on a `NodeJS` server but I've come accros examples of using `jimp` in `React` applications.

Here's my code

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getImage = async () => {
    try {
      const image = await Jimp.read("...");

      image.pixelate(20);

      console.log("Image processed successfully");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error processing image:", err);
    }
  };

  getImage();
}, []);
```